# How to use FlexiGrid with Java?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery-plugins, datagrid

I have tried to search on google but not able to find the solution.

Does anybody know:
how to use FlexiGrid with java for loading data and configuration from .java files?

I want to load configurations + data from server side.

Comment: see http://www.kenthouse.com/blog/2009/07/fun-with-flexigrids/

Comment: @Tomingram: That I already seen. But I want example in java code. And in that tutorial also, configurations (columns, sortorder etc..) are define in .js file, whereas I want all configurations should be load from server side only.

Comment: @MendorhaKorat there are many things wrong with your question primarily you are asking for a tut not a solution to a problem. It sounds perhaps you are not understanding the `client <-> server` technologies, don't run before you can walk and look at setting up a simple web service in java (netbeans has a few tuts on this), then investigate how you can **a.** *request data with javascript*, **b.** *respond to a request appropriately*, **c.** *traverse data with javascript*, it's all there on web just maybe not here :-)